# Wrong Touchscreen mapping

Tags: display, windows-10, touchscreen, hid

Using two Touchscreens (Could not install the win7x64 Drivers from acer.com, win10 sais its not compatible):

1. Acer T230H (Primary)
2. Acer T230H

If i put a finger on the 1st, the Position of the touch-indicator is correct.

But if i put a finger on the 2nd touchscreen, the Position of the touch-indicator is on the **first touchscreen**.

If i put a finger on the left side of the second Display, Windows indicates the left side of the first Touchscreen.

Questions:

1. Is there a fix to map the second Touch-HID to the second Display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Tablet-Preferences and press "Setup". ^
[image]
The displays will fade into white and press <kbd>Return</kbd> until the message is on the display. Now place the finger on the display.

Comment: if someone doesn't find this window maybe this does help: [Tablet PC Settings is Missing](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-hardware/tablet-pc-settings-is-missing/b55ab19d-ee5a-4973-84c5-39aabd723d31)